# Why session is automatic/random expired or site logout with https?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using `Codeigniter`  and this is my `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'application/session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.example.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = TRUE;
```

Site is automatically redirect to https using .htaccess.

When site working on http only with sess_match_ip, cookie_secure and cookie_httponly with FALSE then it is working fine. but when working on https it logout automatically/randomly.

What is the proper configuration for https?

Comment: Are you by any chance serving your site from multiple load balanced servers?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Yes, site is running through load balancing.

Comment: there's the issue... the files driver will not work for you. Let me elaborate in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Since your site is running on load-balanced servers, the issue is not the `cookie_secure` atribute but the `files` driver.

When using the `files` driver, the session information is stored locally on the server that responds to your request. Depending on your load-balancing configuration, the user may change servers between requests. If that happens, when changing servers, the new server will not have the user's session information and thus he'll be logged out.

You have basically two choices here:

1.- Tweak your load-balancing configuration to enable sticky sessions of some sort. This will prevent, in most but not all cases, that the user jumps between servers. It's by far the easiest solution, but it has some drawbacks. If a server goes down and the load-balancer HAS TO move the user to another server, he'll be logged out, so one of the benefits of load-balancing will not be such in your case.

2.- Change your session storage to another driver (such as `database`) that's independent of the server who is responding to the user. Contrary to the `files` driver (in which each  application server stores its own local session info), a `database`, `redis` or other session driver would use a single centralized storage for session data. So, regardless of the user jumping from server to server on each request, he'd remain logged in seamlessly.

My suggestion would be to go with the second choice, try using a database (the CI documentation is very self-explanatory on this matter) and you'll be fine :)